# Passing a Parameter From One Template to Another

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am attempting to write a web app with Play using the template system that is provided. I am trying to separate the templates into header and content area. Below is the code that I have written for the templates:

Content:

```
@(file: models.File)
@header(@file.title)
<h2>@file.title</h2>
<img src="@file.fileLocation">
```

Header:

```
@(title: String)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>@title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
```

The error that I am receiving is:

```
2: illegal start of simple expression
[error] @header(@file.title)
[error]         ^
```

It looks like I'm trying to pass the title parameter into the header template incorrectly. What syntax should I use to pass the title parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Play template parser recognises `@` as the start of a Scala expression, but it uses magic to figure out where the end of the expression is. (Something like looking for closing parens or braces, I think).

So in your code, `@header(@file.title)` is all Scala code, rather than HTML template, and the second `@` is unnecessary. You just need `@header(file.title)`.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I knew that the second @ was causing the problem, but wasn't aware of how to fix the issue.